# Multiple paths in php.ini open_basedir on Windows

Tags: windows, php, iis

I'm attempting to use multiple paths for my php open_basedir config value, in php.ini on a windows server.

The line I'm using is:

```
open_basedir = E:/Websites;C:/PHP/includes/
```

Unfortunately, it's ignoring the second entry. Whenever I try to execute code in the C:/PHP/includes directory (this example happens to be PHPUnit), I get

PHP Warning:  require(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(C:\PHP\includes\PHPUnit\PHPUnit-3.6.10\PHPUnit\Autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s) : **(E:/Websites)** in C:\PHP\includes\PHPUnit\PHPUnit-3.6.10\phpunit.php on line 41

Note, it's not even showing the second item in the paths list. Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

Am I right in thinking that semicolon (;) denotes a comment? If so, how do I separate the entries, as the manual doesn't make it clear

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget put quotes `"` around whole path, and AFAIR windows is using different notation? try sth like that: `open_basedir = "E:\Websites;C:\PHP\includes"`

Comment: the quotes did it for me on windows server 2012 with php 5.4.14, thanks

Comment: Not working from the command-line: _php.exe -t "%DOCROOT%" -d open_basedir="%TEMP%;%DOCROOT%" -S 0.0.0.0:8000_

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.

Just use a simple colon `:` as a separator, then it works.

**Note for clarity:** "Under Windows, separate the directories with a semicolon. On all other systems, separate the directories with a colon." (from the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir))